# $f(x^2)$ even or odd

Tags: functions

I've been working on the following example:

**Is the following even, odd or neither: $f_{0}(x^2)$, where $f_{0}(x)$ can be any unknown function**

I've tried the following:

---

1) for example I assume $$f_{0}(x^2)=x^3$$ Then: $$f_{0}(x^2)=x^2 \cdot x$$ $$f_{0}(x^2)=x^2 \sqrt{x^2}$$
$$f_{0}(x)=x \sqrt{x}$$

Now I take $f_{0}(-x)$ which is: $$f_{0}(-x)=-x^{1.5}$$

This is neither $f_{0}(x)$(would be even) nor $-f_{0}(x)$(would be odd) so it is neither even nor odd. Is this true?

---

2) My second attempt is:

$f_{0}((-x)^2)=f_{0}(x^2)$ which shows that it is even.

---

I got 2 opposite results. Which of my attempts is true?

Comment: $g(x):=f_0(x^2)$ is even by attempt 2).

Comment: Now, I got 2 opposite comments. Which one is true? @ozo: Why is my first attempt wrong?

Comment: @Hakim Of course you can tell. The composition $f\circ g$ is always even when $g$ is even, with no condition on $f$.

Comment: We are not asked to show that $f_0$ is even. We are asked about the composition $f_0(x^2)$.

Comment: You are mixed two things. $g(x)=f(x^2)$ is even because $g(-x)=f((-x)^2)=f(x^2)=g(x)$, but in your argue you calculated $f(-x)=(-x)^{1.5}$ not $g(-x)$

Comment: Your first attempt is wrong because it violates the rules of logic. You are not allowed to "assume" that $f_0(x^2)=x^3$ unless that equation is a hypothesis, which it is not.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: Why is the following wrong: If I try the test for even functions (as in my second attempt) I put the minus sign somewhere else: $f_{0}(-(x^2)). Now it is not even any longer. Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Because, as you say, you put the minus sign somewhere else, thus you are no longer loyal to the definition of an even function.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are getting confused by $f(x^2)$. $f$ is a function $f:x\longmapsto f(x)$.

Consider $g:x\longmapsto g(x)=f(x^2)$.

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ g(-x)=g(x)$. Therefore $g$ is even. So is the function $x\longmapsto f(x^2)$ of course.

In your first attempt you did not compare $f((-x)^2)$ and $f(x^2)$.

Comment: Thanks, but I have got some more questions: 1)In my first attempt the function $f(x)=x\sqrt{x}$ is only defined for positive numbers so I can't make $f(-x)$.  

2) Isn't my second atttempt wrong because: In the function $f(x^2)$  I have to treat $x^2$ as $x$ in $m(x)$. If I want to test $m(x)$ for being even I have to take $m(-x)$. Now, if I do the same with $f(x)$ and then I get: $f(-(x^2))$ which is not $f((-x)^2)$. Why is this reasoning incorrect?

Comment: @user50224 1) $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$ so if $x<0$ you cannot apply $f$ to $x$. 
2) Your second attempt is correct, and my answer is only a more detailed explanation of what you said.

Comment: Why is the following wrong: $$g(x)=f(x^2)$$ Then: $$g(-x)=f(-(x^2))$$

Comment: @user50224: because $g(-x)=f((-x)^2)\neq f(-(x^2))$!

Comment: Thanks! Now I know _that_ my reasoning was wrong but I still don't know _why_ it is wrong. 1. Could you maybe prove your equation: $$g(-x)=f((-x)^2)\neq f(-(x^2))$$? 

2._Why_ was my reasoning in the comment above ( $g(x)=f(x^2)$ then $g(-x)=f(-(x^2))$ wrong? 

Up to now I understand _that_ it is wrong but I have no idea _why_ it is wrong. 

_Why_ is the following wrong?: I have $g(x)=f(x^2)$ Then I can see this also as $g(a)=f(b)$ where $a=x$ and $b=x^2$. Then I want to test for being even: $g(-a)=g(a)$ if it is even. Then  f(-b)=f(-(x^2))=f(b) which is not true. Where is the mistake?

Comment: It should be obvious, take e.g. $f$ such that $f(x)=f(x^3)$. Then $f(-(x^2))=(-(x^2))^3$ while $f((-x)^2)=f(x^2)=(x^2)^3$. If you don't get it I can just advise your to go back to the definition of a function...

Answer (score 4):

Let's just prove a more general proposition:

Given two functions $f,g$ with $g$ even, the composition $f\circ g$ is even, with no conditions on $f$.

Proof: $\forall x\quad f\circ g(-x)=f(g(-x))=f(g(x))=f\circ g(x)$   QED

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x)=f(x^2)$ then
$$g(-x)=f((-x)^2)=f(x^2)=g(x)$$
so it is even

Comment: Why is the following wrong: $g(-x)=f(-(x^2))$

Comment: It contradicts the definition of the above $g$. By its definition $g(-x)=f((-x)^2)=f(x^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

In your first attempt, you attempt to "solve" for a function $f_0$ such that $f_0(x^2) = x^3$.    You come to the conclusion that if we define $f_0(x) = x^{1.5}$, then we'd have $f_0(x^2) = x^3$.

This is true if you only consider $x \geq 0$, but it is not true for $f_0$ over all of $\Bbb R$.  In your third line, you make the substitution $x = \sqrt{x^2}$, which only applies when $x \geq 0$  (otherwise, we'd have $x = -\sqrt {x^2}$).  As a result, the conclusion you reached was invalid.